# Spark-submit throwing error from yarn-cluster mode

Tags: apache-spark

How do we pass a config file to executor when we submit a spark job on yarn-cluster?

If I change my below spark-submit command as **--master yarn-client** then it works fine , I get respective output

```
 spark-submit\
 --files /home/cloudera/conf/omega.config \
 --class com.mdm.InitProcess \
 --master yarn-cluster \
 --num-executors 7 \
 --executor-memory 1024M  \
 /home/cloudera/Omega.jar \  
 /home/cloudera/conf/omega.config
```

**My Spark Code:**

```
 object InitProcess
  {
      def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
           val config_loc = args(0)
           val config = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File(config_loc ))
           val jobName =config.getString("job_name")


      .....
      }

  }
```

I am getting the below error

```
17/04/05 12:01:39 ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception:     com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'job_name'
com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'job_name'
```

Could someone help me on running this command in --master yarn-cluster ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The different between `yarn-client`  and `yarn-cluster` is that in `yarn-client` the driver location is on the machine running the `spark-submit` command.

In your case, the location of the config file is `/home/cloudera/conf/omega.config` which can be found when you running as `yarn-client` as the driver is running from the *current machine* which holds this full/path/to/file.

But can't be access in `yarn-cluster` mode, as the driver is running on other host, which doesn't holds this full/path/to/file.

I'd suggest execution the command in the following format:

```
spark-submit\
 --master yarn-cluster \
 --num-executors 7 \
 --executor-memory 1024M  \
 --class com.mdm.InitProcess \
 --files /home/cloudera/conf/omega.config \
 --jar /home/cloudera/Omega.jar omega.config
```

Sending the config file using --files with its full-path-name, and providing it as parameter to the jar as it filename (not with a full path) as the file will be downloaded to unknown location on the workers.

In your code, you can use `SparkFiles.get(filename)` in order to get the *actual full-path-name of the downloaded file on the worker*

The change in your code should be something similar to:

```
       val config_loc = SparkFiles.get(args(0))
```

> [SparkFiles docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkFiles.html)
>
> public class **SparkFiles**
>
> Resolves paths to files added through SparkContext.addFile().

Comment: I tried by Changing the code and spark-submit command and I got the below error 17/04/05 14:17:49 ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.spark.SparkFiles$.getRootDirectory(SparkFiles.scala:37)
 at org.apache.spark.SparkFiles$.get(SparkFiles.scala:31)


17/04/05 14:17:49 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 15, (reason: User class threw exception: java.lang.NullPointerException)

Comment: @SurenderRaja - can you please add some debug to your code? print the value of `args(0)`, and if the value is not null, print the value of `SparkFiles.get(args(0))`?

Comment: When I println(args(0)) then it prints as omega.config .This NullPointer exception is thrown exactly at line SparkFiles.get(args(0))

Comment: 17/04/05 14:34:02 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Waiting for spark   context initialization
     17/04/05 14:34:02 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Waiting for spark context initialization ... 
     17/04/05 14:34:02 ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
      java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.spark.SparkFiles$.getRootDirectory (SparkFiles.scala:37)
  at org.apache.spark.SparkFiles$.get(SparkFiles.scala:31)  .Adding the full errors

Comment: @SurenderRaja - The problem is that SparkFiles.get() will work only after spark context is initialized.

Comment: @SurenderRaja - do you have any distributed disk like: `hdfs` or `s3`? if so, the simple solution will be to place the config file in `hdfs` or `s3`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139985/discussion-between-surender-raja-and-yaron).